# What does Error C00D07C9 mean when trying to set up wireless sync?

Tags: zune, wireless-sync

I've had a few goes at trying to set up wireless sync since I got my phone, but I get Error C00D07C9, with a message saying that:

> Zune was unable to connect to the wireless access point.

Even though the laptop running Zune (on Windows Vista), and connected to the phone is quite happily connected to the access point (and onward to The Internet). I'm using a HTC Titan.

What might be causing this to not let me set up wireless sync?

Comment: I have a Lumia 900 and I am having the same issue, I have even tried turning the firewall off completely and the error code still comes up, has anybody managed to fix this?

Comment: I should also point out that I am using Windows 7, so this issue isn't just your HTC or Vista...

Comment: I know your problem is with *Windows Vista* but you question indeed is not specific. So I want to share that in *Windows 8* Zune WiFi sync does not work right now according to an MVP on [Microsoft Answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp7-sync/wireless-sync-windows-8-c00d07c9/8cfce655-18c7-4251-9031-861b1cce4dea?tm=1348710730023).

Answer (score 3):

This might happen when you are on a network where some specific ports are blocked by the router or firewall. (common on public networks)

See also this microsoft support site

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/952304#method4

Comment: My anecdote in support: I used to use ESET Smart Security for my firewall, and it was a hassle getting wireless sync set up using it. Since then, I've transitioned to the built-in Windows firewall and Microsoft Security Essentials, and Zune was able to autoconfigure it to let it through. Now I don't have any issues.

Comment: @GeertvdC It seems that the link you're referring to is dead.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/952304#method4)

**Error C00D07C9**
You may be connected to a Public-level network.

**Resolution**
This error can appear when the computer that Zune is installed on is connected to a Public network location. The Public network location blocks certain programs and services from running to help protect your computer from unauthorized access while you're connected to a network in a public place. If you're connected to a public network and Windows Firewall is turned on, some programs or services might ask you to allow them to communicate through the firewall so that they work properly.

If your computer is connected to a Public network this behavior is normal and you need to allow the Zune program and the Zune Wireless Configuration Service to communicate through your firewall. If your computer is actually connected to a network at work or at home (or a network you trust) then:

1. Open the Network and Sharing Center by clicking the Start button, and then clicking Control Panel. In the Search box, type "network", and then click Network and Sharing Center.
2. Click Public network and then click Work network or Home network.

Comment: The network they're both on is a "private" (Home) network, so this workaround doesn't resolve my particular issue

Comment: Are you **certain**? The error number you provided says otherwise. If you are sure then check your firewall settings and make sure Zune is allowed to go out.

Comment: Without knowing what firewall settings to check, that's a bit difficult; I allow the UAC prompt, so I would *expect* it to do all the right things (there are no third party firewalls installed)

Comment: I am on a corporate network right now, so this is coming from memory. Sorry if it is a tad wrong. 1. Open windows Firewall. 2. select "Allow a program or feature through" 3. if Zune is not selected in the list click "Add new", browse to the install folder and choose the exe.

Comment: Like i said, that is from memory. Hopefully it will be close enough to at least let you see if zune is in the list.

Comment: Even with the firewall disabled, it still doesn't work :(

Comment: hmm..your antivirus *could* possibly be blocking it. Turn that off and try again. Make sure your firewall is off too. Basically we want to make sure Zune has no obstacles to go through right now.

Comment: Also, I have seen some people say to make sure it is plugged in for a few minutes before trying. It won't work when the device is syncing

Comment: Joe, I have the same issue. I've checked firewall settings every application containing word 'Zune' is added as exception. My network is private as well. And DHCP on my router is enabled. Still I am getting the same error. I'm not sure what is the reason, still the article you are referring to is at some point useless.

Comment: I have no antivirus installed, so that is not a reason as well.

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 1):

Answer for Windows 8:

> I know your problem is with Windows Vista but you question indeed is
>   not specific. So I want to share that in Windows 8 Zune WiFi sync does
>   not work right now according to an MVP on [Microsoft Answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp7-sync/wireless-sync-windows-8-c00d07c9/8cfce655-18c7-4251-9031-861b1cce4dea?tm=1348710730023). – Vitor
>   Canova♦ Sep 27 '12 at 1:59

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp7-sync/wireless-sync-windows-8-c00d07c9/8cfce655-18c7-4251-9031-861b1cce4dea?tm=1348710730023

As of May 2013, wireless sync of Windows Phone 7.8 with Zune in Windows 8 is still not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I had experienced the same issue, and after researching on this page http://support.xbox.com/en-AU/xbox-on-other-devices/windows-phone-7/wireless-sync
you can see on section 'Compatible wireless networks' that states 'Zune players do not support the 802.11n standard.'

Since my network is 801.11n, I guess I won't be able to sync my phone...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem running my Nokia Lumia 610 connected to a Windows XP computer, I tried turning off the Windows Firewall located in the Control Panel and it did not work. So I turned the firewall back on and added Zune to the Exceptions list of programs in Windows Firewall. Next I tried the other recomendation mentioned by tomekpe by turning on Internet coneccion sharing in my Nokia phone (this is located in settings, do not unplug your phone from the usb cable plugged to your computer). It gave me an error on my Nokia phone when I tried to turn on Internet Connection Share, so I closed the error message and went back to my PC and enable Wireless Sync again in Zune, and it worked, it should work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Also had the same problem, below solution solved it (taken from srndolha.wordpress.com/2014/03/12/resolved-c00d07c9-error-setting-up-zune-wireless-sync ):

> On the Windows® Phone connected by USB cable to the computer (and
>   having Zune software running):
>   1. Open Settings, select Internet Sharing and try to turn it on; it should respond with an error, as Internet connection sharing is not
>   available while connected to the PC using a cable; ensure Internet
>   Sharing is turned back off;
>   2. On the computer, go to Zune software application, select Settings and Wireless sync, and try setting it again: you may be surprised to
>   have it working this time!
>
> I’m not sure why Internet Sharing is involved (that’s what I called
>   spectacular about this fix), but it surely resolves the problem!
>
> Update: I found out that although the steps above might work on a
>   Domain/Work network, the actual wireless sync process may not be run
>   unless the network is Private/Home. And the limitation for 802.11n may
>   still be in place.